# Writing to a Socket which wasn't "accepted" on a ServerSocket?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a simple server that looks like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4999);
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(is.read());
    }
}
```

It accepts a single client socket, reads from it forever and prints out the number that was sent from the client socket.

I have a client like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int id = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 4999);
    OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
    while (true) {
        os.write(id);
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        System.out.println("Sent");
    }
}
```

It connects to the server and sends the number it received as command-line argument forever.

1. I start the server.
2. I start a client like `java -jar client.jar 123`.
3. Then I start another client like `java -jar client.jar 234`.
4. No errors happen on neither the server side nor the client side.
5. Each client prints the `Sent` message every 1 second, neither gets blocked.

The server only prints `123` until the end of times.

My questions:

1. What happens with the bytes written by the second client?
2. I would expect the second client to receive an error or get blocked or something, but nothing happens. Why?

Note: I know that this code is bad and I should handle clients in threads and call `ServerSocket.accept()` and all that jazz.

**Update**:

Based on the accepted answer the solution is to create the server like `new ServerSocket(4999, 1);` where `1` is the size of the backlog. `0` would mean to use whatever the default setting is configured in Java.

By using `1` there can be only one connection in a "non-accepted" state. Anymore client trying to connect gets a connection refused!

Comment: You are blocking the server's listener. The server must to handle "onAccept" and listen for another client

Comment: @ChristosThemelis Sorry, I don't get your point. Also, please read my note at the end - this is on purpose.

Comment: If you don't handle it correct, the server side will not listen for second connection

Comment: @ChristosThemelis I understand, that wasn't the point. Please read the question carefully and see the accepted answer (I was looking for the insight it gave).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The bytes written by the second client will go into the client `Socket`'s send buffer, since you're writing to a socket that doesn't have an established connection yet.  Eventually the send buffer will fill up.  You could try playing with `Socket.setSendBufferSize()` to see what happens when it fills up.
2. A `ServerSocket` has a listen backlog for connections that haven't been `accept`ed yet.  The second client's connection is in the backlog, and if the server would ever get around to `accept`ing it (which it won't, with your code, but there is no way for the client to know that), it would be established and the client's send buffer would be sent merrily along.  You could try calling the constructor `ServerSocket(int port, int backlog)` with a backlog of `1` to see what happens to the client when the listen backlog fills up - it should get `connection refused`.

Comment: 1. Actually, I did play with the send buffer size: nothing happened :/ My expectation was that after the send buffer fills up there'll be an error, but there's none. 2. Ah, the backlog, I never really understood that parameter in the class' constructor. Makes sense now! I'll try playing with it. And based on this I guess the send buffer doesn't work like I've imagined - overflowing with an error - but instead overflown bytes are silently discarded and not sent to the server when that starts accepting the clients data. Thanks!

Comment: @KohányiRóbert "*My expectation was that after the send buffer fills up there'll be an error, but there's none.*" - your expectation is wrong. There is no error. TCP has flow control. When the sender's send buffer fills up, the sender will simply block until the buffer is sent and the receiver acks it. There is no overflow. In your case, it is possible that the send buffer is actually being sent, but the server is not reading the data, so the receive buffer on the server's side will fill up, blocking the sender anyway until the receive buffer clears room. Which it won't ever do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hmm, this makes sense. I did a little test to no avail. I don't want to update to my question, because I got my answer, I understand what happens conceptually, but it doesn't work or I make a mistake. I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/kohanyirobert/2e80d8612b4bb6f943f6340f647e53ba). The backlog is set 1 (setting to 0 means default behavior). RCVBUF set to 1 byte. In reality that the 1st client connects and is served, the 2nd is connected (not served) and the 3rd will be refused only. However the 2nd client won't ever receive an error. Not sure about what happens and why.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert again, because there is no error condition. The 2nd client will keep sending until it can't send any more, and then it will block waiting for permission to send again. If you want an error, put the client socket into non-blocking mode. The 3rd client is rightly rejected since you set the backlog to 1 slot and the 2nd client occupies that slot.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "2nd client will keep sending until it can't send any more,  and then it will block waiting for permission to send again" I might have left out a piece of information (no more room for characters in the comment). I've configured the client RCVBUF to 1 byte, but still the 2nd client kept sending, without getting blocked. So what you say doesn't happen in reality (or I'm missing a piece still). Putting the client into non-blocking mode didn't have any effect - I didn't expect it to have (see the [updated gist](https://gist.github.com/kohanyirobert/2e80d8612b4bb6f943f6340f647e53ba)).

Comment: @KohányiRóbert The client has a send buffer independent of the server's receive buffer. Setting the server's receive buffer to 1 byte is too low, no socket stack will accept that, it will cap how low the buffer can really go. Read RCVBUF after setting it to get its real size. The client will happily keep sending until its own send buffer fills up, regardless of whether the server's receive buffer already filled up beforehand. Setting the client to non-blocking does make a difference, because once the client's send buffer finds up, subsequent sends WILL fail until the send buffer is sent.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for all the insights, but sockets in Java seem to behave differently and/or we're talking at cross purposes here. Let us continue in chat sometimes if you'd want to get to the bottom of this. A few final thought on my behalf: I set the server/client rcv/snd buffers separately to 32 bytes and on the server after accepting the 1st client I "stopped" reading from its input stream. The 1st client stopped sending after a while (when the server rcv filled up I guess). The 2nd client kept sending indefinitely, never stopping.

Comment: @KohányiRóbert Java sockets use platform sockets internally, and they behave as I described. I've been programming with sockets for 20 years, I know what I'm talking about. The 2nd client sends "indefinitely" because you are not accounting for the fact that you sleep 1 sec after each write. At 4 bytes per write, and a minimum send/receive buffer size of 4K (which is far more than 32 bytes - I told you sockets cap how low you can set the buffers), your client should take 17 minutes to fill up its send buffer while the server is not reading from that client.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right! :) I left buffers at their default size (65535 bytes) and removed sleep from the client. This way both the accepted and the non-accepted client blocks (the server doesn't read the accepted socket's data) indefinitely. Non-blocking mode still doesn't throw an exception when this happens, Java's `SocketChannel.write` will just report that 0 bytes were written - so there's at least a way to detect it. ([Updated the gist accordingly](https://gist.github.com/kohanyirobert/2e80d8612b4bb6f943f6340f647e53ba).) Thanks for the insight!